# What's the difference between async.log and async.dir?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I found [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) has two util functions: `log` and `dir`.

But I don't find many differences between them. See the code:

```
var async = require('async');

var x = function() {
    this.name = 'Freewind';
}
var hello = function(name, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        callback(null, 'hello ' + name, 'nice to see you ' + name, x, {a:'123'});
    }, 200);
};

async.log(hello, 'world');
async.dir(hello, 'world');
```

It prints:

```
hello world
nice to see you world
[Function]
{ a: '123' }
'hello world'
'nice to see you world'
[Function]
{ a: '123' }
```

You can see the only difference is the later one has more `'` around the results.

Is there any example to show what `dir` can do but `log` can't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Says it in the docs:

**[async.log](https://github.com/caolan/async#log)**

Logs the result of an async function to the console. In general it uses [console.log](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.dir.28object.29)

**[async.dir](https://github.com/caolan/async#dir)**

Logs the result of an async function to the console using console.dir to *display the properties of the resulting object*. In general it uses [console.dir](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API#console.dir.28object.29). If you use FIrebug, it is like the view in the DOM tab.

Comment: I don't find any difference between `console.log` and `console.dir`, do I miss something?